# Unable to resolve module `perf_hooks`

Tags: node.js, typescript, react-native, node-modules, typescript-typings

I am trying to use perf_hooks from the nodeJS Performance API in my React Native project. Below is my code

```
import {performance} from 'perf_hooks';

export const measure = (
  target: Object,
  propertyKey: string,
  descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
) => {
  const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
  descriptor.value = function (...args) {
    const start = performance.now();
    const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
    const finish = performance.now();
    console.log(`Execution time: ${finish - start} milliseconds`);
    return result;
  };

  return descriptor;
};
```

I keep getting the same error.
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `perf_hooks` from `src/utils/metrics.ts`: perf_hooks could not be found within the project.

Performance API is available from node version 8.x and my node -v response is 10.16.1.

I see that there is perf_hooks present in my node_modules as well under the `@types/node/perf_hooks` folder.

Comment: There are lots of platform facilities provided as module by the NodeJS runtime. This isn't a NodeJS app, is it?

Comment: You are right. This isn't a nodeJS application, it's a react native app. But I see that the node_modules contains the perf_hooks folder which means that nodeJS utilities are available. But I'm unable to use them.

Comment: Hmm that should work then or at least the error should be different.

Answer (score 3):

First import node types

```
$ npm i --save-dev @types/node
```

Now change the import statement to this:

```
import { performance } from 'perf_hooks';
```

Comment: Note that I copied code from node.js docs that used `const { performance } = require('perf_hooks')`. Took me a while until I realised this. I changed to `import` and the types started working.

Answer (score 3):

Update / upgrade your node version and try a fresh install. This should solve the issue.